# Path for a circle in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, path, geometry, shapes

I can use an Ellipse shape but for my purposes it there a simple Geometry I can set for the Data property of the Path class to have a circle?

That is 


What should go into the Data property to display a circle.

I exported a cirlce path in Expression Belend it came out with a long convoulted string when I expected something simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an `EllipseGeometry` like this:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

If you need to express this as a string in Path Markup Syntax, you may construct the circle from two halfs like this:

```
Data="M0,0 A50,50 0 0 0 0,100 A50,50 0 0 0 0,0"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Blend, the simplest thing to do would be make your circle with an `Ellipse` Then just Choose Object->Path->Convert to Path

The length of the Data string isn't something you're going to be able to do much about since it's what is required. If you want simpler, just use an `Ellipse`, unfortunately I don't know of a better answer. Hope this helps.